# Coordinate free proof of Gauss-Bonnet theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Can the theorem be proved invariantly, without any reference to charts,frames, basis vectors or coordinates?

Comment: Please state what do you exactly mean by Gauss-Bonnet theorem (there are several formulations with this name). And how do you explain what is a surface "without charts"?

Comment: The "standard" Chern proof using Cartan's structure equations and transgression of differential forms is coordinate-free.

Comment: Standard proof for chern Gauss Bonet theorem is not coordinate free. I think I made this clear in the description. It uses matrices and basis vectors to write down forms.

Comment: You can make the Chern proof coordinate free.  Also, the Hopf proof is coordinate free, but it's for submanifolds rather than abstract Riemann manifolds.

Comment: @Riu: yes, the standard textbook proofs use charts and coordinates, but, as alvarezpaiva says, the Chern proof, when using Cartan's structure equations, goes through directly on the frame bundle, without using any charts, or coordinates.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336303/calculation-of-the-sphere-surface-using-only-intrinsic-variables

Comment: This is the question , how to make any proof that uses frames, coordinates and charts into an invariant proof as I specifically asked.

Comment: Manifestly invariant as in the  description

Comment: No matter what, frames will be there, but it might be possible to write Chern's proof without ever mentioning frames explicitly. Something like the following: A Riemannian metric is equivalent to an $\mathrm{O}(n)$ action on the tangent bundle. The connection and curvature are global $\mathrm{o}(n)$-valued forms on the associated principal bundle. Proceed from there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  A beautiful conceptual coordinate-free proof is presented
by Berwick-Evans in https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.5383.
It obtains both sides of the Chern–Gauss–Bonnet theorem
as two limits of a partition function associated
to a certain (rather simple) 0|2-dimensional supersymmetric sigma-model.

Answer (score 2):

[Chern's famous proof of Gauss-Bonnet](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/chern7.pdf) in all dimensions is basis-vector and coordinate free (and also intrinsic, i.e. not requiring some embedding in say a euclidean space). Reason for this is the use of differential forms, which have both these properties, which in turn are properties of its underlying algebra, the exterior algebra.  The [exterior product is basis-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra). [Do Carmo's book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540576181) is a good place to learn about this aside from Chern's quite accessible and short paper.

Comment: Read the description ,I think we have a misunderstanding on what coordinate free is. I asked for a proof without basis vectors and coordinates.

Comment: The very nature of differential forms is that they do not require a choice basis. One can find a projection onto a chosen basis, but this is neither required nor done in Chern's proof. Chern's proof also does not use coordinates in the sense of any substrate space where points in space can be identified by coordinates. Rather it uses Cartan's moving frames to traverse over the surface in question. As all that is needed is derived from the surface itself independent of any embedding, this is an intrinsic proof. If this does not answer your question you need to clarify how it doesn't.

Comment: Oh well then I'm sorry. I also meant no frames ..